# What's the time complexity for the loops?

Tags: python, loops, time-complexity

```
thelist = [[2,3],[],[]]
n=len(thelist)
for i in range(1,n):
    if i <= k:
        thelist[i].append(1)
        for j in thelist[i-1]:
            c = j+1
            thelist[i].append(c)
```

I am trying to figure out the time complexity for the code. Isit O(n^2) or O(n)? I think it's O(n^2) because there's 2 loops but then again I'm not using n times to run the 2nd loop so it might be O(n). I trying to get the time complexity of O(n).

Comment: Will the initial size of `thelist` change during runtime?

Comment: Nope, it will fill the other 2 sublists after the loop is done.

Comment: If the list is fixed in size then the amount of work done is constant

Comment: Does it mean the time complexity would be O(n)? Because n is the size of the list.

Comment: The first `for` loop iterates till n, so it is atleast O(n). Now, the worst case  for second loop, which at most iterates to n-1, which makes O(n-1) for second loop which is equivalent to O(n) as well. Since they are nested I think it is O(n^2). Isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Amount of items we iterate through in `thelist` is n-1
- Amount of items in the sublist before the main list you're iterating through will be 2 for the first iteration, then +1 every time (2, 3, 4, ..., n, n+1). However, we can ignore the n+1 since we won't be iterating through that. So, worst case we iterate through n times.

Hence it's `O((n-1)*n)`, which we generally just round to `O(n^2)`.